# I want to hide the next div on each click. But can't find a solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click the "fixed" div then it will hide the next div for each click. But it can't hide except only first div. Here is the source code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fixed").click(function(){
     $(this).next().hide();
  });
});




<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="fixed"></div>
    <div class="first">First</div>
    <div class="first">Second</div>
    <div class="first">Third</div>
    <div class="first">Forth</div>
    <div class="first">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method with [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo-class selectors. Where  [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) will select all visible elements and [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) would select the first one among the selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fixed").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.first:visible:first').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed">click</div>
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="first">Second</div>
  <div class="first">Third</div>
  <div class="first">Forth</div>
  <div class="first">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please help me if these divs are hidden and I want to show them as same process.

Comment: @RokibulHasan :  simple , `$(this).nextAll('.first:hidden:first').hide();`

Comment: Thanks a lot I have tried this just a moment ago. Its really simple.

Comment: Again disturb you. Would you mind to suggest me any source to learn jquery with a short time for a biginners.

Comment: Okey. Thank you so much. Wish you be happy all day long.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of which is the next element to be hidden:

```js
var sibs = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > div")
var sibCount = sibs.length - 1;    
var nextHide = 0;

$(function(){
    $(".fixed").click(function(){
        nextHide++;
        $(sibs[nextHide]).hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fixed">FIXED</div>
    <div class="first">First</div>
    <div class="first">Second</div>
    <div class="first">Third</div>
    <div class="first">Forth</div>
    <div class="first">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just reading the jQuery API doc so that I can refer to that using a link in my answer... Can you add that?

Comment: @Jay What are you asking for?

Comment: [This](https://api.jquery.com/next/)... Don't you think that adding a link to `next()`'s document would help future comers?

Comment: @Jay JQuery is used much too often for solving simple problems. Too many people start using JQuery without understanding JavaScript and the native APIs that are available to them. Can `next()` be used? Sure, but why use a hammer when a thumbtack is all that's needed? In fact, in many cases, using JQuery will result in slower performance than not.

Comment: Valid point, sir! Even my colleagues tend to use stuff without reading the docs.. That is quite funny as well as annoying (just sharing personal experiences :P)

Comment: @RokibulHasan Did you mean Jay or me (Scott, who's answer this is)?

Comment: Really sorry...it's you(Scott Marcus). Thanks a lot. I have to track of that element first. But I can't. Now its solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Imagine you have

```
<div id='content'>First</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>
<div id='content'>Second</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>
```

What you actually need to do is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Good luck

Comment: @Jay kennyS for life!

Comment: I know that I am getting banned for this... I am selling p90 asii fn for 4k xD

Comment: @Jay hahaha Rush B